# How to pass command line argument in electron

Tags: node.js, electron

I just started using electron. I have a doubt about how to pass command line arguments in `electron` when I'm using `npm start` to run electron.

In `Node.js` I am using: `node server.js one two=three four`
command prompt  for :

```
var arguments = process.argv.slice(2);
arguments.forEach(function(val,index, array) {
  console.log(index + ': ' + val);
});
```

In `Node.js` is working. I need to know how can I make this work in electron.

Can someone please give a solution for this?

Comment: That's the right way, only you would do `electron . one two=three four`

Answer (score 20):

The way of passing arguments will be same, the only thing you have to take care is path of electron. In `package.json` its written `npm` start will perform `electron main.js`. So you will have to execute this command explicitly and pass arguments with "proper path of electron" i.e `./node_modules/.bin/electron`. Then the command will be

```
./node_modules/.bin/electron main.js argv1 argv2
```

and these arguments you can access by `process.argv` in `main.js`

and If wish you to access these parameters in your app then there are following things to do :

1.In your main.js define a variable like

```
global.sharedObject = {prop1: process.argv};
```

2.In your app just include remote and use this `sharedObject`

```
const remote = require('electron').remote;
const arguments = remote.getGlobal('sharedObject').prop1;

console.log(arguments);
```

3.Output will be `["argv1", "argv2"]`

Comment: You can use `require('electron').remote.process.argv` directly to get the arguments to the main process.

Comment: just careful when calling remote in your gui, this can be used as an exploit. your system api is exposed from this. Its best practice to access these in the main process, then store into the globals, or push into your gui using IPC events. Also note, arguments should be immutable. Its best to not change, and if you have to use a different variable, such as one in your globals..

Comment: in my case with electron v10.x I am getting `remote` is undefined error in the main process. I was able to access CLI arguments by installing Electron's process https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/process  in the main process you can access arguments by `const process = require('process');` `args = process.argv`

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `--` to separate the **npm** arguments from your app's arguments.  This is a fairly common idiom in POSIX (Unix, Linux, etc.).

```
npm start -- one two=three four
```