# It's possible send signal to app(electron) by external source?

Tags: electron

It's possible send signal to app(electron) by external source?

Atom gets through the send line command to add new projects for example

```
atom . -a
```

I could not find any examples, not even in the source code of the Atom.

**UPDATE:**
Is a command line argument during atom startup and with a running instance of atom.

Comment: Not knowing atom: Is this a command line argument during atom startup or does this command interact with a running instance of atom?

Comment: both. during atom startup and with a running instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How to parse command line arguments in Electron?

This is no different than parsing command line arguments from NodeJS using `process.env`. The questions [has been answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30815446/how-to-pass-command-line-argument-in-electron), so I'll not go into much more detail here.

#### How to interact with a running Electron instance via command line switches

First of all I'll assume you restrict the number of possible running instances to a single one - otherwise you'll have to figure out which instance of the program to talk to (possibly via adding the process id to your command line arguments.)

Let's code. For your main.js:

```
var shouldQuit = app.makeSingleInstance(function (commandLine, workingDirectory) {
    if (mainWindow) {
        if (mainWindow.isMinimized()) mainWindow.restore()
        mainWindow.focus()
        /* Insert your Code handling the passed command line arguments here */
    }
});
```

This snippet is called when a second instance is attempted to be launched, instead it brings the first instance into focus. This can easily be adapted to pass the commandLine arguments saved in `commandLine` to the original instance.

Additionally, you'll want to prevent the second instance from actually opening and quit instead:

```
if (shouldQuit) {
    app.quit();
    return;
}
```

Comment: *"This can easily be adapted to pass the commandLine arguments saved in commandLine to the original instance."* - this is the part I am trying to understand. Easy for one man is not easy for all. :(

Comment: Hi there @spartygw, I've added a comment at the position where you can add your code that you would like to handle the passed command line arguments. Let me know if you have any more specific questions.

Comment: That actually helped a lot. It didn't occur to me that the command line args from a separate instance would show up and be available right there but sure enough they are! Thanks!