# Electron get data from custom extension file

Tags: node.js, electron

I am using electron and trying to achieve a result where the **user clicks on the saved file which opens the electron application and gets the data of the file**.
So far I have done is:
1) Created the custom extension registry and added the file open command using reg file.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.wtpd]
@="Water Treatment Plant Design File"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.wtpd\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\\\Users\\\\user\\\\Downloads\\\\wtpd_file.ico"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.wtpd\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.wtpd\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.wtpd\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\ENV\\electron.exe\" \"%1\""
```

2) Now it opens the electron application but i want to get the data inside of the `.wtpd` file in order to calculations.

I have tried to use this but the links in this examples are broken. https://www.theodo.fr/blog/2015/12/link-files-to-application-in-windows/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Windows passes the file path as an argument to the application (your Electron app in this case). So you can use `process.argv` to get the file path.

```
var filePath = process.argv[1];
var data = fs.readFileSync(openFilePath, 'utf-8');
```

Obviously you may want to add checks such as `process.argv.length >= 2` to ensure the argument was passed (in case the application was opened manually, not invoked by windows). But this is generally how you could get the file contents.

Comment: well got the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30815446/how-to-pass-command-line-argument-in-electron