# I'm trying to change the default application for a certain file extension so that I can run my javascript file automatically on startup of the file

Tags: javascript, executable, default, file-extension

Currently I am making a viewer for IFC files in javascript which is supposed to render a 3D mesh. Meaning that I want to use that javascript application as a default application to open IFC files. But I am unsure on how to start the rendering process when I actually click a file with that file extension. How can I receive the file path from where I opened the file so I can load it directly into my application.

Comment: What OS (Windows, linux, etc)?

Comment: Using Windows :-)

Comment: Which engine do you want to run the javascript? The browser's?

Comment: Not sure what you mean but I have an executable file which I built so its a desktop application

Comment: What runs the javascript?

Comment: Im basing my application on this git repository https://github.com/IFCjs/examples/tree/main/simple-electron

Comment: Im pretty new to javascript so Im not sure what you mean

Comment: Im assuming that nodejs runs the javascript as I built it via npm

Comment: Ok I see. It likely is "electron". So the build step makes the .exe of your modified code of that example. Gotcha. Ok so now you want to associate `*.ifc` files to your application?

Comment: In your code do you have lines that read the parameters (ala command line parameters) of which IFC file to open? If not, you'll need to code that part. Then in Windows, right click any `.ifc` file -> Open With -> Browse -> Choose your app --> Tick always

Comment: Right now I have a file explorer to open the ifc file, I did the windows part but that does not open the ifc file right away since that is not coded in. my question was on how about to code that part

Comment: This might help although its dated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30815446/how-to-pass-command-line-argument-in-electron   I google searched "electron javascript get command line arguments"